# Assistance with only inserting the most recent location into my table.

Tags: sql

I have a text file with about 4 million lines like these. Imagine the following are just one line.

Oct-15-2018,11:16:46,iPhone,[Tom],wg-a225-3002F Brm.rab.wireless.Aefp.WWW,Fountain,F8-12-9A-1J-48-B9)

I've been using load data infile and just uploading the entire .txt file to my table. My DB ran out of space and I have to figure out a way to just  update the most recent time into the table for that specific user or insert if the user doesn't exit yet. I'm completely lost and my skills are pretty limited. Could someone point me in the right direction on where to start?

Thanks!

Comment: just check if `max(date/first_column) =sysdate `if it is then  mantain an id for your table if not find some unique column in your table then check if that id is already in the db or not then place `insert/update` query

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: ..._normally_ what you do is load the data into a staging table of some sort (usually with the natively provided bulk-load utility), then run statements off of that to get it to the final tables/rows, and then just clear the staging table.  Bulk-loading has limited transformation capabilities, so you may be able to get some of the columns to non-text immediately.

Answer (score 0):

At first check your free storage. Maybe you should empty the recycle bin.

In Oracle:

```
select  
   t.tablespace_name,
   round(t.bytes/1024/1024,0) USED,
   round(t.max_bytes/1024/1024,0) TOTAL,
   round(t.max_bytes/1024/1024 - t.bytes/1024/1024,0) FREE
from USER_TS_QUOTAS t;
```

In MSSQL/SSMS:

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DbName, 
name AS FileName, 
size/128.0 AS CurrentSizeMB, 
size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS INT)/128.0 AS FreeSpaceMB 
FROM sys.database_files;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Answer posts are for answers, not clarifying questions. If you need further info, the comments under the OP are where they should be.